# Is it possible to fill a PDF template using itext technology . the goal is to build entirely my PDF on the server side before send it to the client

Tags: itext

Due to the fact that Safari doesn’t allow plugin to be installed on devices
I need to know If  it’s possible to fill a PDF template  using itext technology  . the goal is to build entirely my PDF on the server side before send it to the client so my client can open it as any PDF 
Is some has a useful  example  ? any link or suggestion

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is more commonly handled by generating the PDF using [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports). Their [getting started guide](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/getting.started.html) contains a bunch of examples which include PDF generation.

If you happen to use that, Spring-MVC provides specific support for using Jasper Reports as a view.